# Symfony 3.4.2 - Unrecognized options "auto_generate_proxy_classes, naming_strategy, auto_mapping"

Tags: symfony, sonata-media-bundle, symfony-3.4

I'm making my first project Under Symfony 3.4
I'm currently looking to install Sonata News Bunfle to create a blog, I'm installing at the same time Sonata MediaBundle.

But I'm having a problem. I'm following the [doc](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/master/doc/reference/installation.html). End I'm having an error when running the command to generate entities.

```
php bin/console sonata:easy-extends:generate --dest=src SonataMediaBundle
```

I't returns this error :

> Unrecognized options "auto_generate_proxy_classes, naming_strategy, auto_mapping" under "doctrine.dbal.connections.default"

Here is the config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver: pdo_mysql
    host: '%database_host%'
    port: '%database_port%'
    dbname: '%database_name%'
    user: '%database_user%'
    password: '%database_password%'
    charset: UTF8
    mapping_types:
                enum: string
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
    #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
    #     e.g. database_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/var/data/data.sqlite'
    #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
    #   3. Uncomment next line:
    #path: '%database_path%'


    auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
    naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
    auto_mapping: true
    types:
                json: Sonata\Doctrine\Types\JsonType
```

I don't understand What happen I'd like to understand to go further in my project.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [reference configuration](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) of Doctrine Bundle: options  `auto_generate_proxy_classes`, `naming_strategy`, `auto_mapping` should be under `orm` part.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        #dbal part
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true
```

Comment: Great ! Thanks a lot :)